# How can I make members of a Team in Minecraft Invulnerable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I have a small Java Server on `1.16.1` and use a [Vanilla Tweaks](https://vanillatweaks.net) datapack ("AFK Display")to have people that stand still for 5+ minutes be considered AFK. This datapack puts them in a team to tell them apart on the Tab list.

I have so far set their `nametagVisibility` and `collisionRule` to `never`, so their nametag cannot be seen and they cannot be pushed around by other players.

Is there a way to prevent these players from taking damage at all? So they cannot even be hit around? Basically making them invulnerable?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that is possible, but you could give them `Resistance 255`, so if they get attacked, they cannot be moved or damaged. Regeneration can be added if needed.

Comment: The problem with that is that they're still being able to take damage and be moved by the knockback. This movement would then make the datapack consider them not afk anymore.

Comment: @ColinShark, I have changed it so the AFK player cannot be moved.